# Is there a simple way to show an image with a frame with Glide?

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I would like to add a frame around my image which I am loading with Glide. My image doesn't have a fix size, so adding frame as a background does not work.
Is there an easy way to make the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is a way .

```
int myWidth = 512;
int myHeight = 512;
int borderSize=20;

Glide.with(yourApplicationContext))
    .load(youUrl)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
        Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bitmap.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bitmap.getConfig());
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
       canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, borderSize, borderSize, null);
       //Now you can use bmpWithBorder on ImageView you want

        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where you have the SimpleTarget, I have my ImageView instance. What should happen with that?

Comment: Then it will directly display the image without any frame .

Comment: With SimpleTarget class you can customise the bitmap that is downloaded over the network . Then you can use the bitmap wherever you want !

Comment: Where should I set my imageview instance inside the SimpleTarget, and how?

Comment: Just below comment .

Comment: Use imageView.setImageBitmap(bmpWithBorder)

Comment: mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmpWithBorder.getBitmap()); Like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145282/discussion-between-rishabh-maurya-and-codeme).

Comment: @codeme Yeah ,but there is no need to use getBitmap() function . Its already a bitmap .